# Can't see someone else's tweets

Tags: twitter

I sent a tweet to someone. It wasn't part of an ongoing conversation. It was just something I sent to them. I asked someone in a forum I was in if they could read the tweet I had sent. This person wasn't the recipient, yet they were able to read my tweet to the other person.

I've NEVER been able to read the tweets sent to someone. If I go into someone's timeline, the only thing I see are tweets that they've sent, as well as replies, etc. But I'm not able to see tweets sent to them. Is there some setting that I"m missing? This is very frustrating.

Comment: No, this is how it is

Answer (score 0):

If you sent a tweet to them by including their @Name in the tweet-text, then it will be visible to the whole world, and potentially seen by

- Everyone who follows you,
- Anyone who searches for something that is in your tweet
- @name if they look in their Connect tab.

This is how Twitter has worked for a long time.

Perhaps you really meant to send them a Direct Message in Twitter instead of a tweet?   If you had use a DM, then it would only be seen by the person, and not on their timeline.